# Error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: gnu-make, openwrt

I'm trying build using make command, But I'm getting following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2.7
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Its saying cannot find -lpython2.7, but I have python2.7 installed. I have googled it around but didn't find proper solution. Need help to to fix this issue.